# Return value when variable is in part of an array

Tags: php

I have this section of PHP code, which takes the response from an API and then checks to see if a particular part of the response matches a variable.

Like below... in the array `attribution` is there a `source_id` that matches `$this_id`?

```
$this_id = 15;
$array = json_decode($response, true);

if (in_array($this_id, array_column($array['data']['attribution'], 'source_id'))) {
      // then do this
}
else {
      // then do this instead
}
```

This works perfectly. What I'm trying to do is get some additional data from this array without having to call the API all over again. The logic would be as above, but then if `true` return the value for `['data']['attribution']['item_number']`. Keeping in mind that there might be a bunch of objects in the `attribution`.

How can I return this value?

Comment: Are you going to pass `['item_number']` in the call to API?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change the `in_array` to `array_search`:

```
$this_id = 15;
$array = json_decode($response, true);
$ind = array_search($this_id,array_column($array['data']['attribution'], 'source_id'));

if ($ind !== false) {
     $found = $array['data']['attribution'][$ind];
     //then do this and also use $found
}else{
     //then do this instead
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This is just what I needed!